# How to get tokenID from Stripe credit card in flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I want to get the tokenID from my credit card. I saw this [Article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-stripe-firebase-d6299e6f76ef) is using `StripeSource.addSource` but the latest stripe package did not have `StripeSource.addSource`. So I do like this:

```
StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
 CardFormPaymentRequest())
 .catchError((e) {
 print('ERROR ${e.toString()}');
 }).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) async {
  final CreditCard testCard =  CreditCard(
  number: paymentMethod.card.number,
  expMonth: paymentMethod.card.expMonth,
  expYear: paymentMethod.card.expYear
 );

 StripePayment.createTokenWithCard(testCard).then((token) {
  print(token.tokenId);
  });
 });
```

But I get the error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalidRequest, Missing required param: card[number]., null)`

Anyone can help me solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: You do not need to create a token once you have a payment method. They are two abstractions for the same thing. Also, Stripe's payment method object does not include the raw card number (as it would defeat the purpose of tokenization). The flow is to save the payment method to a state variable and then confirm a payment intent with it per the examples here: https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment#-example-tab-

Comment: @ttmarek thank you for your reply. Actually I want to do charge for customer. But I don't know how to add new card and get the token. That why I try do like that but got error.

Comment: Right, so in order to accept a payment you first [create a payment intent server-side](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#creating-a-paymentintent) and send it's client_secret to your app. Next create the payment method (it's the same as a Token) like in your code, just remove the CreditCard call, and save the payment method to a variable. The last step is to confirm the payment with the client_secret and the payment method like so: https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L151-L168. I'd review the calls in that repo and test them out.

Comment: @ttmarek thank you for your reply. I have try this but after I check the log in stripe dashboard, the object is payment_intent. I want my object is "charges".

Comment: Payment Intents can be thought of as a newer version of Charges. Its Stripe's recommended way to process payments. A successful payment intent creates a Charge in the background automatically. So if for whatever reason you need access to a Charge object you can get one from a payment intent! It truly is the way forward and the recommended path if you're just starting out.

Answer (score 3):

I do like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static String secret = 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  TextEditingController cardNumberController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController expYearController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController expMonthController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  initState() {
  super.initState();

  StripePayment.setOptions(
    StripeOptions(publishableKey: "pk_testxxxxxx", merchantId: "Test", androidPayMode: 'test')
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: cardNumberController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Card Number'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: expMonthController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Expired Month'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: expYearController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Expired Year'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('card'),
              onPressed: () {
               final CreditCard testCard =  CreditCard(
                        number: cardNumberController.text,
                        expMonth: int.parse(expMonthController.text),
                        expYear: int.parse(expYearController.text)
                      );

              StripePayment.createTokenWithCard(testCard).then((token) {
                print(token.tokenId);

                createCharge(token.tokenId);
              });
            },)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createCharge(String tokenId) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount': '2000',
        'currency': 'usd',
        'source': tokenId,
        'description': 'My first try'
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        'https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges',
        body: body,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ${secret}','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      );
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (err) {
      print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @peter I have tried your approach but my app kept crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a token if you have a `paymentMethod`.
This code works for me:

```
PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod();
  paymentMethod = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
    CardFormPaymentRequest(),
  ).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
    return paymentMethod;
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('Errore Card: ${e.toString()}');
  });
```

After this, you can check the `paymentMethod` and if not null you can go ahead with charging the card